# silverlight - change child window position when opened

Tags: animation, silverlight-4.0, childwindow

How do I change position of childWindow control when it is opened?

I want to do that because I want to make resize animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in expression blend. After creating new animation at time frame `0` size will be correct and at time frame `1` re-sizing can be done. Window loaded we can call the storyboard.

Please refer [this link](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/silverlaw/archive/2010/06/07/how-to-rotate-a-regular-silverlight-childwindow.aspx)